# How to get the difference in days between two dates excluding only Sundays in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Same as the question asked above. Date difference must exclude on Sundays but include Saturdays

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far in solving your problem?

Comment: Please provide a link to your previous question and give more details about your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.busday_count`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) with `weekmask` for exclude on Sundays but include Saturday:

```
out = np.busday_count(date1, date2, weekmask='1111110')
```

In DataFrame:

```
df['diff'] = np.busday_count(df['start_date'].to_numpy().astype('datetime64[D]'), 
                             df['end_date'].to_numpy().astype('datetime64[D]'), 
                             weekmask='1111110')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference in days between two dates excluding only Sundays in a pandas dataframe, you can follow these steps:

```
Import the necessary libraries:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Create a pandas dataframe with the two dates:
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-05'],
                   'end_date': ['2023-01-10', '2023-01-15']})
```

Convert the 'start_date' and 'end_date' columns to datetime format:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
```

Create a function to calculate the difference in days excluding Sundays:

```
def get_days(start_date, end_date):
    days = np.busday_count(start_date.date(), end_date.date())
    return days
```

Apply the function to the dataframe to calculate the difference in days:

```
df['difference_days'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_days(row['start_date'], row['end_date']), axis=1)
```

The resulting dataframe will have a new column 'difference_days' that contains the calculated difference in days excluding Sundays between the 'start_date' and 'end_date' columns.`enter code here`